# Accessing indiviual scss files in Zurb Foundation 4 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

I've installed the foundation 4 gem into my rails app, and have access to a foundation_and_overrides.scss file to change certian foundcation variavles.

However, I'd also like to make changes to the specific .scss files, such as _top-bar.scss

How can I access these files within the Foundation gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the gem does not have a way to generate the files for you. They will be included from the gem directly.

You can always manually add Zurb files to your project without using the gem. That is the way to go if you want to make changes.

Also, you can override the css rules easily in the overrides file. Why do you want to make changes directly?

Comment: Overriding does seem like the sensible option. Thanks for your assistance.